# JavaScript generating heading with special characters JSON

Tags: javascript, json, special-characters

I have a problem with special characters.
my JavaScript is generating a image gallery. It is also generating a heading for the gallery and this heading is produced from the directory path name. The heading is basicly the folder name in which the images are. My problem is, that some of the folder names has special characters and this is causing some problems with generating the gallery heading.

Below you can see cutout from my code. Would be great if somebody can help me :)
Thanks and sorry for the bad english.

````
    jQuery.getJSON("/images/galerie", function(galerie_index){

        for(let gi in galerie_index){

            let entry = galerie_index[gi];

            if(entry["type"] !== "directory"){
                return;
            }
            let galerie_pfad = "/images/galerie/" + entry["name"];

            create_heading_element(entry["name"]);

            process_galerie(galerie_pfad);
        }

    });
}

function process_galerie(galerie_pfad){

    let wrapper = create_wrapper_element();

    jQuery.getJSON(galerie_pfad + "/index.json", function (image_index){
        for(let eintrag in image_index){
            create_image_element(wrapper, image_index[eintrag], galerie_pfad + "/" + eintrag);
        }

    });

}```
````

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you've quoted. Most likely, the problem is mismatching text encodings: the server side code producing the JSON is not ensuring that it handles text encoding correctly at each stage. For instance, it may be that the characters in your directory names are encoded with [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or [ISO-8891](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), but then it's sending those character avlues with a response it claims is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). (That's just an example, but it's a common one.)

Comment: If you haven't read [Joel Spolsky's essay on text encodings](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), I recommend doing so. But basically, to solve this: 1. Identify what text encoding the characters in the directory names are. 2. Intentionally convert them from that text encoding to whatever encoding your server is using for the response it sends the browser.